# How to change html element display with eval value?

Tags: asp.net, css, eval

```
<td scope="col" style='display:<%#Eval("RETURNSTATUS")=='0'? "none" : "inline"%>'>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="İade Et" />
</td>
```

I wrote this code but dont work.Can you help?

Comment: Can you show the aspx code for the RETURNSTATUS control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your reply but it don't work.I solved problem like this.I create hiddenfield and set value by #eval

```
<td scope="col" >

 <asp:Button ID="btnReturn" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("InventoryId")%>'     Text="İade Et" OnClientClick="return confirmReturnInventory()" />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Status") %>' />
 </td>
```

In c# behind,I wrote method preRender event of repeater

```
protected void rptInventoryList_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptInventoryList.Items)
        {
            HiddenField hdnStatus = (HiddenField)ri.FindControl("hdnStatus");
            Button btnReturn = (Button)ri.FindControl("btnReturn");
            btnReturn.Visible = hdnStatus.Value == "0";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code?

```
 <td scope="col" style='<%#Eval("RETURNSTATUS")=="0"? "display:none" : "display:inline"%>'>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="İade Et" />
</td>
```